# Calling FBML & Ajax on click

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml

I need an expert to review this script, it seems like this Javascript is not being called on onclick

```
function send() {    

  var ajax = new ajax();  
  ajax.responseType = ajax.FBML;  
  ajax.requireLogin=true;  
  ajax.ondone = function(data) {  
    document.getElementById('message').setInnerFBML(data);  
  }  

  var queryString = {  
    'message' : document.getElementByID('message').value,  
    'ibid' : , document.getElementByID('ibid').value,  
    'txt_color' : "000000",  
    'name' : document.getElementByID('new_name').value,  
    'hideme' : "0"  
  };  

  ajax.post('http://test.com/it.php', queryString);      
}
```

HTML used to call the JS function:

```
<input type="button" value="Send" onClick="send();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong case in `getElementByID` (notice the capital D) here:

```
var queryString = {
'message' : document.getElementByID('message').value,
'ibid' : , document.getElementByID('ibid').value,
'txt_color' : "000000",
'name' : document.getElementByID('new_name').value,
'hideme' : "0"
};
```

Should be:

```
var queryString = {
'message' : document.getElementById('message').value,
'ibid' : , document.getElementById('ibid').value,
'txt_color' : "000000",
'name' : document.getElementById('new_name').value,
'hideme' : "0"
};
```

Comment: @user: Also noticed an extra comma here `'ibid' : , document`. Check out your code thorouly. When you say **does not work**, it doesn't mean anything. It would be easier if you could mention exact error that comes up :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the above code gives a couple of errors [screens shot of the javascript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8RAz.png), as Mr.Sarfaz said above please remove the comma after `'ibid': ,` to `'ibid':`.

Also, I believe that there is class constructor called `ajax` because you referred it in your function `new ajax()`. if not please define the constructor and return an XHR instance/whatever the FBML instance.